# Crawling multiple tables using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I need data from different tables. In this case tables [0:17] and table [18]. I don't need a table [17]. How to solve it in one Scrapy spider. This solution does not work. Scrapy currently fetches data only from tables [0:17], but not from the table [18].

```
def parse(self, response):
    table = response.xpath('*//table')[0:17]
    for tab in table:
        trs = tab.xpath('*//tr')[1:]
        for tr in trs:
            name = tr.xpath('.//td[2]/text()').extract_first()
            price = tr.xpath('.//td[3]/text()').extract_first()
            yield {
                'Name': name,
                'Price': price
            }

def parse_next(self, response):
    table = response.xpath('*//table')[18]
    trs = table.xpath('*//tr')[1:]
    for tr in trs:
        name = tr.xpath('.//td[2]/text()').extract_first()
        price = tr.xpath('.//td[3]/text()').extract_first()
        yield {
            'Name': name,
            'Price': price
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

yor list slice could be done 2 times, something like this:

```
table = response.xpath('*//table')[0:17]
table = table + table[18]
```

if [18] is not the last item, you also can doo this:

```
table = response.xpath('*//table')[0:17]
table = table + table[18:]
```

edited:

```
table = response.xpath('*//table')[0:17]
table_final = table + response.xpath('*//table')[18:]
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo, but It doesn't work, probably because the modifier 'table' is not a string. Does not work either 

    table = response.xpath('*//table')[0:17]
    table18 = response.xpath('*//table')[18]
    table = table + table18

Comment: sorry, i do a mistake, if you do this, it will work. You can us '+' to cancat lists in python. (edited response)

Comment: It is the same solution I told in my first comment and this not working. TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "Selector") to list. Variable 'table' in this case in Scrapy is not the string and not the list.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `TypeError` you can do one of these solutions:

1. Concatenate with list element:

```py
table = response.xpath('*//table')[0:17] + [response.xpath('*//table')[18]]
```

2. Use append:

```py
table = response.xpath('*//table')[0:17].append(response.xpath('*//table')[18])
```

Also you can make your own solution work, but it's a little bit messy solution and overdo. By the way you can callback your `parse_next()` in `parse()` and send *name* and *price* as meta like:

```py
yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=parse_next, meta={'Name':name, 'Price':price})
```

Then do rest of the work in `parse_next`.